# How to build Kazoo RPM files from source code?

Tags: centos-7, rpm, rpmbuild

I am experimenting with kazoo and wanted to install it from source code. I am able to generate a deployable release but i am not able to build rpm from it. I heard that spec file is needed to build rpm but couldn't generate one . Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question. Please read https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/ and you can try https://xsuchy.github.io/rpm-spec-wizard/